# How can you run an individual gulp task without exiting the watch process?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am fairly new to using gulp and node in general, and am interested to know how I would be able to run a single gulp task while gulp.watch() is running. Is this possible?? Some tasks I have don't need to be watched but I am wondering how I can utilise these tasks without exiting the default process.

eg. running this task from the command line while watching

```
gulp.task('psi', ['psi-mobile', 'psi-desktop']);
```

It would be really convenient to run this on the fly without exiting the watch process. Hope that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Open a new terminal window and run `gulp psi` inside the folder.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. I thought I might've had to do it in the script! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open new terminal and from there launch the single task like:

```
gulp --color minify-css
```